# Pandas df.query for column names with spaces?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pd.query to filter based on multiple columns, however my column headers have spaces in them. Is there a way without removing the spaces to use query()? I tried single quotes as follows (keeping in mind that the real data/query is much more complex than this), but no luck:

```
x1 = "ab"
x2 = ["ab", "ac"]
x3 = ["ab", "ad"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"t 1": ["a", "b", "ab"],
                   "t 2":["b", "x", "ac"],
                   "t 3":["a", "w", "ad"]})

df.query("'t 1' in @x \
         & 't 2' in @x2 \
         & 't 3' in @x3")
```

Note: I'm on pandas 0.23

Edit:

While I understand that this can be done with more traditional `df[df['t 1'].isin(x1) ...` syntax, the query actually created is dynamic and usually involves 10 or so filtering criteria, so it's not ideal to use that method. Is there a way to use query? or an alternative solution?

Comment: There is an open [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6508) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, @YakymPirozhenko. Guess the traditional filtering syntax it is...bummer.

Comment: FYI: I ended up temporarily renaming the columns so I could use query and then renaming them to their original names afterwards.